# From where do I get the featx.py module?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Good day,
I'm trying some examples to classify text from the "NLTK cookbook" and the book references to a featx.py module which contains several feature extractors.
The problem is I cannot find that featx.py module anywhere.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't find it anywhere? Where did you look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick googling points to [this site](https://bitbucket.org/japerk/nltk-trainer/src/791a1abf26c4/nltk_trainer/classification/featx.py).  `japerk` is the author of that book, so it fits.  So, I'd download that `nltk-trainer` package and try using it with NLTK.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the code package for the book from the Packt website here: http://www.packtpub.com/support/6164.